# How can I wrap a text element inside an <svg> at a certain width or inside another <svg> element?

Tags: svg, word-wrap

According to the [svg specification](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TextLayoutAuto), there is a way to auto-wrap a text element by defining a content area.

> Text is automatically wrapped when a content area is specified in the
> ‘text’ element. The content area defines the outermost container for
> wrapping text. A wrapping context (set of exclusion areas) may also be
> given. The actual wrapping area is defined by subtracting the wrapping
> context from the content area. The wrapping context may also be
> reduced by the value of the shape-padding property. The effective area
> of an exclusion may be enlarged by the value of the shape-margin
> property.

The specification includes images of how this appears, but no examples of actual code.

Can someone provide an `<svg></svg>` code example, which includes a text element wrapped at a certain width or inside another shape in the `<svg>`?

Comment: No browser has implemented auto text wrapping.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson, I edited my question for more clarity.  This is what the specification says:    
   

_Text is automatically wrapped when a content area is specified in the ‘text’ element. The content area defines the outermost container for wrapping text. A wrapping context (set of exclusion areas) may also be given. The actual wrapping area is defined by subtracting the wrapping context from the content area. The wrapping context may also be reduced by the value of the shape-padding property. The effective area of an exclusion may be enlarged by the value of the shape-margin property._

Comment: What the specification says and what you can actually use because there's some software in existence that implements that part of the specification are two different things. What's the point of an example of something that you can't use.

Comment: Aha, I understand.  So auto text wrapping is in the svg specification — but no browser has implemented that aspect of the specification.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.